# Как заменить ViewPager + Tabs на Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Вообщем есть такая разметка.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="false" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="#333"
    app:itemTextColor="#333"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Во ViewPager есть три фрагмента. У меня есть Fragment X. Только когда я хочу его открыть мне не нужен ViewPager и Tabs. Просто чтобы был один фрагмент на весь экран(+Toolbar). Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: Разметка в этом вопросе более, чем полностью лишняя. Нужен код

Comment: @pavlofff, не соглашусь, разметка здесь нужна таки... Она поясняет как надо изменить её для реализации заявленного функционала...

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам поможет оборачивание `CoordinatorLayout` в `FrameLayout`, задание ему `id` и добавление фрагмента вашего (с `Toolbar` в разметке) в этот `FrameLayout`.

При этом подходе добавленный фрагмент должен, по идее, отображаться поверх `CoordinatorLayout` со всем его содержимым. `Toolbar` в его, фрагмента, разметке нужен, т.к. предыдущий будет перекрыт как и все остальные компоненты `CoordinatorLayout`.